# Finding Permutations of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a reference data table having columns as codes and values.

For e.g. there are three code types viz. A, B, C.

The table is as below:

```
Code      Value
---------------------
 A1       a_one
 A2       a_two
 B1       b_one
 B2       b_two
 B3       b_three
 C1       c_one
 C2       c_two
 C3       c_three
 C4       c_four
---------------------
```

I have a requirement where the input will be code types and output should be all permutations between the input code types.

For e.g. if the input code types are A and C, the output of my sql should be:

```
col_1     col_2
---------------------
 A1       C1
 A1       C2
 A1       C3
 A1       C4
 A2       C1
 A2       C2
 A2       C3
 A2       C4
---------------------
```

Similarly if the input code types is A, B, C, the output of the sql will have three columns with all the permutations between A, B, C viz. A1 B1 C1 to A2 B3 C4.

I have no idea how to start on this. So any hints will be useful.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don’t understand where the numbers come from. You say that if input are A and C, one of the outputs are A2, C4. Why not the other way around A4, C2? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Lennart I think he wants to do a dynamic select columns base on input. If that is the case, IF-ELSE statement in select column is the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is one of those rare cases where a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafycrojo.htm) is actually what you want. A `CROSS JOIN` will give you the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets, which means all possible combinations between the values in those sets.

Example:

- Table A with column 1 contains values 'a' and 'b'
- Table B with column 2 contains values 'c' and 'd'

The following `CROSS JOIN` query (note there is no 'join condition' specified, on purpose):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A
CROSS JOIN B
```

will return the following result:

```
1   2
--------
a   c
a   d
b   c
b   d
```

I created an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3764d/2)** to show you a possible solution. You can tweak it a bit to see if this is what you need. (Note it's an Oracle fiddle, as there is no DB2 option.)